# GitHub pre-receive hook display warning message

Tags: git, github, githooks, pull-request

I am able to validate commit via Github pre-receive hook. But, instead of blocking commits with non-zero exit code in pre-receive hook, is tgere a way to display warning messages with exit code 0?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.  From the `pre-receive` section of `githooks(5)`:

> Both standard output and standard error output are forwarded to `git send-pack` on the other end, so you can simply `echo` messages for the user.

As long as you ensure your script exits 0, the push should succeed.

Comment: Yes, the push succeeds but since the pre-receive hook does some validation check and this being Enterprise GitHub, I was looking from deployment point of view. Such that instead of rejecting commits, I intend to display warning messages for a certain period of time and then change it to an error. What I notice is, if the scripts bails out with exit code 0 none of the echo statements get displayed. So am looking for a way to display warning msgs

Comment: The [documented behavior](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.19/admin/policies/creating-a-pre-receive-hook-script) is that the standard output is passed back to the user.  If that's not what you're seeing, then that's a bug, and you should contact GitHub Support about that.